# Mocking RabbitMQ for testing

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring application where I am using RabbitMQ for publishing and consuming messages. The connection factory is created in the following way:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.4.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="RabbitMQ" class="com.services.RabbitMqListenerService" />

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        host="${rabbitmq.host}" port="${rabbitmq.port}"
        username="${rabbitmq.username}" password="${rabbitmq.password}" cache-mode="${rabbitmq.cacheMode}"
                               connection-cache-size="${rabbitmq.connectionCacheSize}"/>
</beans>
```

But while I am running the tests instead of creating this connection I want to create an in-memory map which will work as a queue for me. This I want to do to make sure all my messages are in sync as the async messages might make the tests flaky.

In spring-boot applications it is very simple to do. In `application.java` I can add below code and it will work:

```
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(environment.getProperty("mock.rabbitmq"))) {
            return new MockRMQConnectionFactory();
        }
        com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory rabbitmqConnectionFactory = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory();
        rabbitmqConnectionFactory.setHost(environment.getProperty("rabbitmq.address"));
        rabbitmqConnectionFactory.setUsername(environment.getProperty("rabbitmq.user"));
        rabbitmqConnectionFactory.setPassword(environment.getProperty("rabbitmq.password"));
        rabbitmqConnectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(
                Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("rabbitmq.connection.timeout")));
        return connectionFactory;   
}
```

I am just not sure how to do the same thing in when I am trying to create rmq beans in the XML file (`rabbitmq.xml`). Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Instead of rolling your own `MockRMQConnectionFactory` you can use [rabbitmq-mock](https://github.com/fridujo/rabbitmq-mock) that will do all the mocking stuff for you

Answer (score 0):

You can have the separate bean configuration file like you showed above for testing.
Annotate your test with following.

> @ContextConfiguration(locations = "rabitmqconfiguration.xml")
>   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

where rabitmqconfiguration.xml will have bean definitions.